# clickstream keyword dimension

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-warehouse, dimension

I'm currently trying to determine how to build out a keyword dimension table. We're tracking website visits to our website, and would like to be able to find the most used keywords used to search via a search engine for the site as well as any search terms used during the visit on the site (price > $100, review > 4 stars, etc). Since the keywords are completely dynamic and can be used in an infinite number of combinations, I'm having a hard time trying to determine how to store these keywords. I have a pageview fact table that includes a record every time a page is viewed. The source I'm pulling from includes all the search terms in a delimited list I am able to parse with a regular expression, I just don't know how to store it in the database since the number of keywords can vary so widely from pageview to pageview. I'm thinking this may be more suited for a NOSQL solution that trying to cram it into a MSSQL table, but I don't know.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What about storing them in a 2nd table like one would normally do in OLTP environments?

Comment: A second table?  I'm not sure I follow, do you mean in a star schema?  I'd like these search terms to be in a easily searchable dimension.  Having to search for items greater than $100 and greater than 4 stars is difficult when all you have to work with is: "minyear=2000,minprice=100,stars=4,category=new" in a single column for a given visit

Comment: What I mean is that you store the visits in `(ID INT PK, ...)` and the keywords in `VisitKeywords (VisitID INT PK, Keyword string PK, Value string)`. That looks like the standard solution to this. Would that work?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you want to analyze the data, there's a few solutions.

But for the amount of data that you are probably analyzing, I'd just create a table that uses the PK of the fact to store each keyword.

```
FACT_PAGEVIEW_ID bigint -- Surrogate key of fact table. Or natural key if you don't have a surrogate.
KEYWORD varchar(255) -- or whatever max len the keywords are
VALUE varchar(255)
```

The granularity of this table is 1 row per ID/Keyword combination. You may have to add value as well if you allow the same keyword multiple times in a querystring.

This allows you to group the keywords by pageview, or start with the pageview fact, filter it, then join to this to identify keywords.

The other option would be a keyword dimension and a many-many bridge table with a "keyword group", but since any number of combinations can be used, this is probably the quicker way and will likely get you 90% of the way there. Most questions, like "what combination of keywords are used most frequently", and "what keywords are most used by the top 10% of the user base" can be answered with this structure.

Comment: so you're essentially using the visit fact table as sort of a dimension to this new keyword fact table or a reverse dimension if you will (storing the PK of the fact in the dimension instead of the other way around).  I'm trying to stick as close to Kimball's methodologies as I can, but I think this should work.  If anyone else has any other Ideas, I'd certainly love to hear them.  Thanks N West and usr!

Comment: Yes. You may still want a keyword dimension if the number of keywords is small and they have other attributes you want to group on. Just replace KEYWORD with the KEYWORD_ID and "value" is your "textual" measure.